# Is there a way to apply colorsys.rgb_to_hsv to pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a csv file with rgb color values in three different columns that I want to convert to hsv using colorsys.

The code I first tried divided the rgb values by 255 to get a value between 0-1 and then I tried to create variables for colorsys.rgb_to_hsv that would target the values in the correct columns. Shown:

```
import colorsys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

index=["R", "G", "B"]

data = pd.read_csv('shirtstesting.csv', names=index, header=None)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df /= 255

print(df)

R = df["R"]
G = df["G"]
B = df["B"]

hsv = colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(R, G, B)

hsvarray = []
for x in df[['R', 'G', 'B']]:
    hsv = colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(R, G, B)
    hsvarray.append(hsv)

print(hsvarray)
```

But I was getting an error saying the truth value of a series is ambiguous. I thought the issue was that I was giving a series so I converted the series to lists with this code:

```
import colorsys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

index=["R", "G", "B"]

data = pd.read_csv('shirtstesting.csv', names=index, header=None)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df /= 255

print(df)

R = df["R"]
G = df["G"]
B = df["B"]

l_1d = R.values.tolist()
l_2d = G.values.tolist()
l_3d = B.values.tolist()

hsv = colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(l_1d, l_2d, l_3d)

hsvarray = []
for x in df[['R', 'G', 'B']]:
    hsv = colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(R, G, B)
    hsvarray.append(hsv)

print(hsvarray)
```

Now the error it's returning is unsupported operand type for list and list.

Not sure what to try now. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
hsv_df = df[['R','G','B']].apply(lambda x: colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(*x), axis=1)
```

or

```
hsv_arr = [colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(r,g,b) for _, (r,g,b) in df[['R','G','B']].iterrows()]
```

Comment: Perfect! This solved everything thank you!